# I need to keep only lines in txt file that contain "#"

Tags: grep

I need to keep only this lines in my text file, which contain symbol #.

I have something like this for example:

```
something #
anything else fxgbdfg
car #
325235363456356 @ dfsjdbfkjfbfds
958395959 #
sdfsnfjkndsnc3r /
```

And I need this:

```
something #
car #
958395959 #
```

Can somebody tell me how to do that in GREP?

Comment: Have you tried `grep '#' yourfile.txt`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

grep \#

Or grep \# filename   if you want to use a file rather than stdin

Comment: And then if I want to delete symbol # from whole text file?

Comment: THen you need another tool-  grep doesn't edit files.  Look at sed, or look at writing a quick perl or python script.

Comment: I cannot delete # from whole text file with GREP?

Comment: You can't delete anything with grep.  It doesn't alter the files, it only searches through them.  Sed is the tool you'd use to do a search and replace.

Comment: OK. And with AWK or SED. How can I do that?

Comment: @user1844845 First of all you read the documentation or a tutorial. Then you make an attempt on your own. If you have a problem, you post a question on StackOverflow. The first two items from [this tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) should be enough to get you started.